# How to setup a wordpress theme store?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created my first WordPress Theme and want to put it up for sale.
When I browsed through existing theme stores I discovered that they have a very easy way to present their themes and documentation on their store website.

Is there a plugin or a set of specific settings that can help me setup a theme store? Following are the functionalities that I am looking for:-

1. Users should be able to preview themes. For ex:- http://www.example.com/themes/theme1 should start showing the theme1
   and http://www.example.com/themes/theme2 should show theme2, but i wouldn't want to recreate content for them - they should share the same blog content. I am also in doubt if this is done through WordPress's multi-site option.
2. On many theme stores I also see a theme selection dropdown bar at the top, which lets users select different themes for preview, has a download and a buy button.

Need some guidance along these lines. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a wordpress website store.example.com with woocommerce and make it yourself.
the themes are all products and the live preview could be a new full wordpress installation with its own database. For example store.example.com/live-preview-theme-1 is just a folder with a wp installation but store.example.com/products/theme-1 is the product in woocommerce